# Windows Containers hosted on Windows 10 lose their DNS

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I'm facing this situation where my windows based containers lose their ability to resolve DNS.

This is what happens

To start a container to test dns resolving 

`docker run -it microsoft/windowsservercore powershell`

From inside the container

`Test-NetConnection google.com -Port 443`

Fails with

> PS C:> Test-NetConnection google.com -Port 443
>   WARNING: Name resolution of google.com failed -- Status: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server
>   ComputerName   : google.com
>   RemoteAddress  :
>   InterfaceAlias :
>   SourceAddress  :
>   PingSucceeded  : False

but should be something like this

> PS C:\Users\asarafian> Test-NetConnection google.com -Port 443
>   ComputerName     : google.com
>   RemoteAddress    : 216.58.204.14
>   RemotePort       : 443
>   InterfaceAlias   : vEthernet (External Virtual Switch)
>   SourceAddress    : 10.98.5.139
>   TcpTestSucceeded : True

I always hybernate the workstation (Windows 10) and on it I operate Hyper-V instances and Docker. The workstation is Windows 10 and from what I can tell when the problem happens is that it uses as DNS the ip of the Windows 10 host.

From within the container

```
PS C:\> ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : c7c016e13be8
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : Deducted
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::bc61:e687:4676:353a%5(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.19.143.229(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.19.128.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : Deducted
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : Deducted
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.19.128.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

`172.19.128.1` is my windows 10 host ip.

At the same time, when the Windows 10 host containers are stuck, everything else resolves DNS normally.

- Any process on Windows 10.
- Hyper-V instances on Windows 10.
- Container's hosted on Hyper-V instances on Windows 10.

Restarting the machine doesn't fix the problem. This is the second time that this occurs. Previous time I had to reset the entire docker installation to fix the issue. I would like to avoid this and understand what the problem is and how to fix it.

Docker version is

```
C:\Users\asarafian>docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce-rc1
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   3476dbf
 Built:        Wed Mar 15 20:33:22 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce-rc1
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   3476dbf
 Built:        Wed Mar 15 20:33:22 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

**Update 1 - 20170408**

As per request of @chris-lawrence comment, the following are an `ipconfig /all` from the host and from inside the container. The interesting aspect is that the dns resolution works from inside the container.

Inside the container

```
PS C:\> ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : 476d22f638ea
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : home

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-53-0A-2A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ad59:83cc:6e64:944a%5(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.19.132.10(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.19.128.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 83891549
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-20-7A-A9-D0-00-15-5D-53-0A-2A
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.19.128.1
                                       192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

On the container host

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : MECDEVASAR03
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : global.sdl.corp
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : global.sdl.corp
                                       sdl.corp
                                       maidenhead.sdl.corp
                                       sheffield.sdl.corp
                                       development.sheffield.sdl.corp
                                       irv.languageweaver.com
                                       languageweaver.com
                                       montreal.sdl.corp
                                       singapore.sdl.corp
                                       bray.sdl.corp
                                       seoul.sdl.corp
                                       idiominc.priv
                                       sdlproducts.com
                                       lan.lon.sdlproducts.com
                                       freetranslation.corp
                                       xyenterprise.com
                                       alterian.com
                                       ams.dev
                                       sdlntt.corp

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (HNS Internal NIC):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-53-04-CB
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f5c8:e8c7:1ad0:d845%26(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.19.128.1(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 436213085
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-AD-0A-F4-18-DB-F2-15-03-E7
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (External Virtual Switch):

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : global.sdl.corp
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 18-DB-F2-15-03-E7
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B8-08-CF-44-25-D9
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B8-08-CF-44-25-D8
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::6d3a:ef28:a057:6108%18(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.103(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, 8 April 2017 16:17:24
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, 15 April 2017 16:24:09
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 45615311
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-AD-0A-F4-18-DB-F2-15-03-E7
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B8-08-CF-44-25-DC
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.global.sdl.corp:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : global.sdl.corp       Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{5C890AAE-6E73-44BB-BB1E-DE8EB4794BF8}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.home:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Just at of curiosity, I've checked the state of the hyper-v instances and they are off. My feeling is that there is something strange going on when the hyper-v(s). I'm mostly suspicious that something strange happens when the system resumes from hybernation when an hyper-v instance was running. I'll do a check....

I did the check and everything is still ok. But the hyper-v(s) are setup for the wired netword adapter and as such on WIFI then don't get network. Could be that in this case they don't interfere.

**Update 2 - 20170411**

As per request of @chris-lawrence comment, the following are an `ipconfig /all` from the host and from inside the container **on the network that has the problem**. At this moment of time the firewall on the container host is switched off, as @GSA had suggested.

Inside the container

PS C:> ipconfig /all

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : d4e9a6d59f93
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-53-00-71
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a08a:68b:1c3d:fe6e%5(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.19.135.4(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.19.128.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 83891549
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-20-7E-30-BE-00-15-5D-53-00-71
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.19.128.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

I notice that the there is only **one** dns entry `172.19.128.1` which is the internal docker.

On the container host

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : MECDEVASAR03
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : global.sdl.corp
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : global.sdl.corp
                                       sdl.corp
                                       maidenhead.sdl.corp
                                       sheffield.sdl.corp
                                       development.sheffield.sdl.corp
                                       irv.languageweaver.com
                                       languageweaver.com
                                       montreal.sdl.corp
                                       singapore.sdl.corp
                                       bray.sdl.corp
                                       seoul.sdl.corp
                                       idiominc.priv
                                       sdlproducts.com
                                       lan.lon.sdlproducts.com
                                       freetranslation.corp
                                       xyenterprise.com
                                       alterian.com
                                       ams.dev
                                       sdlntt.corp

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (HNS Internal NIC):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-53-04-CB
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f5c8:e8c7:1ad0:d845%26(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.19.128.1(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 436213085
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-AD-0A-F4-18-DB-F2-15-03-E7
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (External Virtual Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : global.sdl.corp
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 18-DB-F2-15-03-E7
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5814:8934:3247:a4bf%10(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.98.5.139(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, 11 April 2017 08:08:21
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, 19 April 2017 08:08:20
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.98.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.98.3.7
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 504945650
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-AD-0A-F4-18-DB-F2-15-03-E7
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
                                       10.98.3.7
                                       10.98.3.5
                                       10.20.3.169
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 10.100.3.100
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B8-08-CF-44-25-D9
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B8-08-CF-44-25-DC
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Wireless External Virtual Switch):

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : global.sdl.corp
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B8-08-CF-44-25-D8
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.global.sdl.corp:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : global.sdl.corp
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{5C890AAE-6E73-44BB-BB1E-DE8EB4794BF8}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

**Update 3 - Problem fixed**

I just upgraded to the Windows 10 creators update and suddenly the problem has stopped. For now, I consider the issue fixed through a Windows Update. But to whoever has a similar issue, I was just a week behind on the updates and I don't believe that that was the issue. To be seen if it happens again.

Comment: Check if your firewall blocking it

Comment: Which firewall? Inside the container or inside the host (Windows 10)? If it is blocking it on the host, then why is everything else working then? Also, how would you explain the sudden change? Is docker doing something on the system that e.g. windows update could override?

Comment: Host firewall. A lot of stuff might work unreliably if it's on.

Comment: Could you post the output of ipconfig /all from the host machine?

Comment: Should it be on the same network? If yes then we need to wait until Tuesday. In the meanwhile I'm going to try what happens while the laptop is connected to my home wireless network.

Comment: It doesn't need to be the same network no, if your on a different network now just the output of ipconfig /all from the host and within the container will help.

Comment: I've update the original post with the extra information. Unfortunately, the dns resolution works. As, when it didn't all other systems worked fine. I'll do an experiment when I'm going to hypernate with a hyper-v running, resume and see if the issue can be replicated in this working network at home.

Comment: Based on the new output that you have posted, I would expect the DNS in the container to be working, which you have confirmed is now. The key difference here is that in your first ipconfig output from the container you can see you only have a single dns server (172.19.128.1) but that in your second output the container has two dns addresses (172.19.128.1 & 192.168.0.1).

172.19.128.1 is in your case the Docker inbuilt DNS server, used to resolve container names to IP addresses, this server will not resolve external DNS names, which is why in your first example the containers have no DNS.

Comment: I've noticed also the difference, when I compared containers hosted on Windows 10 with ones hosted on win2016 VM on the sheet laptop. The weird thing is that it normally works and at some point it stops. Last time I reset docker and fixed the issue. I would like to understand why and avoid the problem if necessary. I can try the same in the wired connection at home.

Comment: In the meantime I've checked with wired connection and it works as with with the wireless one.

Comment: I'm back on the network that has the problem. @GSA switching off the firewall didn't make any difference.

Comment: @ChrisLawrence. I've added a new update for the request you made to post the `ipconfig /all` from the host machine. This is from the wired network that has the problem and the container still doesn't resolve DNSs because it only has the internal dns server entry.

Comment: @ChrisLawrence what do you think? Is this a bug with docker when combined with hyperv on the same host?

Comment: Problem was solved by the Windows 10 Creators update.

Comment: There is a thread with a similar problem running on docker forums. [Networking issues with Windows Docker containers](https://forums.docker.com/t/networking-issues-with-windows-docker-containers/31070/2)

Answer (score 1):

One of the Docker samples tells you to run this:

```
  RUN Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters' -Name ServerPriorityTimeLimit -Value 0 -Type DWord
```

This is supposed to address some issue with DNS inside your windows container. Not sure it will help you, but worth a shot.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not working currently with containers and the issue had had already stopped for some time before stopping, and hence I can't verify. But it's an interesting suggestion to keep in mind for future reference and for others that might run into same issues.